# How to ping an IDN domain with its non-ASCII name?

Tags: 12.04, dns, ping, internationalization

For all I see, I cannot `ping` (or `dig`) [IDN domain names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) using their non-ASCII names, only their ASCII 'backend' with `xn--` prefix. I am about to add several such names to the configuration of a DNS server I manage, apparently it works with browsers, but not with lower-level tools, which is somewhat inconvenient, as looking up `punycode` names every time I test or debug something is a major nuisance.

E.g. http://ąćęłńóśźż.pl (apparently 'Hyperlink' formatting option mangles the IDN name, so not using it here on purpose) - a test page for checking if browser supports Polish IDNs - works with Firefox, but not with `ping` or `dig`.

Is there some way (PPA, patch, whatever) to obtain such functionality?

Using `12.04`, `iputils-ping 3:20101006-1ubuntu1` and `dnsutils 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `dig` man page:

> **IDN SUPPORT**
>
> If dig has been built with IDN (internationalized domain name) support, it can accept and
>          display non-ASCII domain names. dig appropriately converts character encoding of domain name
>          before sending a request to DNS server or displaying a reply from the server. If you'd like to turn off the IDN support for some reason, defines the IDN_DISABLE environment variable. The IDN support is disabled if the variable is set when dig runs.

so it is supported ...

What you probably need is http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/idn2 It is in devel so probably not installed by default.

> **idn2**
>
> Internationalized domain names (IDNA2008) command line tool

---

Then this will work:

```
ping $(idn2 ąćęłńóśźż.pl)
```

Comment: `ping $(idn2 ąćęłńóśźż.pl)` works indeed, same for `dig`.

Comment: can I borrow that comment? >:)

Comment: Sure ;) Thanks, I think I'll go with this solution, it's simple enough.

Comment: The answer is self-contradictory. In spite of `idn2` package installed, neither dig(1) nor host(1) support IDN on their own, although man pages claim they do.